# BroadcastReceiver Force to close app android - Xamarin

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am wanting to check the status of my Wifi/3G connection, but when my application is closed when I lose my signal connection. I use a code found on the network as an example. Tested in the emulator and when I take the 3G connection the app is forced to close. this code is simple and got the logs. I'm use Xamarin plug.

Log ERROR: http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/2389/hmjz.png

```
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    public static TextView txtNote;

    static string teste2;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        txtNote = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

        button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };

    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        IntentFilter mIFNetwork = new IntentFilter();
        mIFNetwork.AddAction(Android.Net.ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction);
        RegisterReceiver(new NetworkChangeReceiver(), mIFNetwork);
    }

    public class NetworkChangeReceiver : Android.Content.BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)

        {

            String status = AndroidApplication10.Resources.NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);

            Toast.MakeText(context, status, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Other Class:

```
public class NetworkUtil
    {
        public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
        public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 0 ;
        public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 3;


        public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context)
        {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context
                    .GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.GetNetworkInfo(ConnectivityType.Mobile);

            int teste = (int) activeNetwork.Type;

            if (null != activeNetwork)
            {
                if (teste == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI)
                    return TYPE_WIFI;

                if (teste == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    return TYPE_MOBILE;
            }
            return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
        }

        public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context)
        {
            int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
            String status = null;
            if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI)
            {
                status = "Wifi enabled";
            }
            else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE)
            {
                status = "Mobile data enabled";
            }
            else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED)
            {
                status = "Not connected to Internet";
            }
            return status;
        }
    }
```